# Remove CSS of an image (CSS is part of a generated code)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to remove the css of an image. My actual code doesn't include this CSS, but it comes from a generate code. I can't touch that neither modify anything that is related to the generared code.

This is my real code

```
<div class="bubble">
  <img id="one" src="/static/webupload/MyronArtifacts/images/descarga.png" style='float: left;' alt="Quotes">
  <p id="comment11">I was very impressed with the unique design and high quality of this pen.
  </p>
</div>
<div class="quote_speech">
  <div class="name" id="author11">By PEDE</div>
  <div class="company" id="company11">September 25,2013</div>
</div>
```

This code is added to a div from the generated code name rightCol

And there is a CSS class declare the following way

```
#rightCol img{
  display:block;
  float:none;
  margin:0 auto 0 auto;
  position:relative;
  border:0;
  padding:3.5px 0;
  backgroun-color:#fff;
  width:166px
}
```

The issue is on width:166px. 
The bad new for me is I can't remove it manually(Generated code).

So I was thinking to use javascript for this.
using this  **$('#one').hasClass('img')**

But this returns me false.

I did a demo getting in JS FIELD getting the CSS. [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/akAJUfe/2)

If I remove the 166px from the CSS it works, but that solution is not available for me. And the has class returns me false. Wondering why?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the background-color property (of generated code) has spelling mistake. Correct it first.

Comment: 'img' is not a CSS class, it is the type of the DOM node.  $('#one').is('img') should return true.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can use `!important` to override this behavior but it is better to declare more specific rule rather than using `!important`

```
#rightCol img#one {
   width: auto;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://jsbin.com/IxEvImU/1/edit)

Answer (score 0):

Hi I checked your demo page and just added one line to your document.ready function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#one').css('width', 'auto');
        randomtip();

    });
```

check and let me know if still problem exist.